# Column with listview inside a Tabbar does not scroll in Flutterflow

Tags: flutterflow

I have the following widget tree where I am trying to use a column with a list view inside a tabbar. When I run the app on the device, the list scrolling does not work.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

[image]